# Filter table by pattern

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, flatten, google-query-language

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rs2UDk5AFPEsWq6sYx2em6VKWX8_EdMoMSzmvbe3mL8/edit#gid=0) is my spreadsheet. I need to display data from the range **A1:J11** as in the example **M1:O16**. Is it possible to implement this with a formula? I will be glad for any help.

Added:

I have a spreadsheet where data is added daily in a format such as the range **A:J**. I need to form a table from this data on another sheet, in which the first column will contain DATE, the second column will contain data for the DAY, and the third column will contain data for the NIGHT. As in the example of **M1:O16**

Comment: Could you explain what you have tried so far? It would be helpful if you could include screenshots to get a quicker visualization of the problem. Please, before updating your question, check the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
={QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(A1:J; "skipping 4")); "where Col1 is not null"; )\
 QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(FILTER(A3:J; MOD(COLUMN(A:J)-1; 2)=0); "skipping 4")); "where Col1 is not null"; )\
 QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(FILTER(A3:J; MOD(COLUMN(A:J);   2)=0); "skipping 4")); "where Col1 is not null"; )}
```

[image]